# Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to implement a simple recurrent network using TensorFlow, but am receiving the above error. I've looked through several answers related to the:

```
"Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type ____)"
```

error, but none so far have addressed "tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor" as the unsupported type. I am receiving this error after trying to implement code from [this tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/) (albeit with a different data-set).

The error occurs on the *history = model.fit* line:

```
# Define the network
epochs_qty = 50
batch_size_qty = 72
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(epochs_qty, input_shape = (train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss = 'mae', optimizer = 'adam')

# Fit the network
history = model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs = epochs_qty, batch_size = batch_size_qty, validation_data = (test_X, test_y), verbose = 2, shuffle = False)
```

The data sets have the following shapes:

```
print(train_X.shape, train_y.shape, test_X.shape, test_y.shape)
>> (1762, 1, 2) (1762,) (588, 1, 2) (588,)
```

I am running the following versions:

- Python 3.7.9
- Windows 10
- tensorflow-gpu-2.3.1
- CUDA Toolkit 10.1 Update 1
- cuDNN v8.0.3 for CUDA 10.1

I have tried disabling eager execution, but this leads to a pile of additional errors, and does not seem optimal for future code development.

Also, I have tried running this code both locally and through a jupyter notebook. Both result in the exact same error, so it seems like my software setup is not the issue.
Can anyone please suggest where to look next for the cause of this error?

Comment: Note that jupyter notebook is not opposite to "locally" (from "locally and through a jupyter notebook").